# Drupal7 multiple joined query

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I wrote a query to my new D7 module, but it doesn't work.

```php
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->join('field_data_field_image', 'i', 'n.nid = i.entity_id');
$query->join('file_managed', 'f', 'i.field_image_fid = f.fid');
$query->fields('f', array('fid', 'filename'))
  ->fields('i', array('field_image_width', 'field_image_height'))
  ->condition('n.type', 'pattern')
  ->execute()->fetchall();
```

I'm waiting for data from a node type (pattern) which has an image field. I tried to join the node with the image field table and the image field table with the file_managed table. But nothing comes.

I tried in pure SQL and It worked fine, but not in D7. What's wrong with it?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the expected and actual results?

Comment: I'm waiting for data from a node type (pattern) which has an image field. I tried to join the node with the image field table and the image field table with the file_managed table.
But nothing comes.